Spring Boot authentication mechanism
I am at an early stage of building my first Spring Boot application and have a very basic question about the Spring Boot authentication mechanism. Specifically, what happens when a user enters the username and password in the form and submits.
My application requires authentication, using a login form, before a user may access any resource. I understand that this will require a security configuration bean that might look something like the following.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers(
                    "/myApp/v1/login"
                    ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/myApp/v1/login")
            .permitAll()
        )
        .logout((logout) ->
            logout.deleteCookies("remove")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done")
                .permitAll()
        );
            
        return http.build();
}

An unrestricted access to “/myApp/v1/login” is required to enable an unauthenticated access to the login form. What happens when the user enters the username and password and submits a "post" request?
Assuming that the “post” is to the same URL (/myApp/v1/login), since the framework does not require authentication for this URL, how does Spring security chain know to intercept the request and authenticate the user?
If the login “post” is to a different URL, say to “/myApp/v1/formLoginSubmit”, and we configure this URL to require authentication, will Spring serve the original login form again and ask for username and password again to even post the credentials? This looks like an endless loop.
If, on the other hand, we allow unrestricted access to /myApp/v1/formLoginSubmit, we have the same question as above. How does Spring security chain know to intercept the request and authenticate the user?
"Posting" the credentials to the same URL works, but I don't understand how.
Posting the credentials to a URL different from the one used for GET does not appear to work. Allowing unrestricted access to the "post" URL simply bypasses Spring's authentication mechanism. Not allowing unrestricted access gets into the loop of serving the login form repeatedly to the user.
Really appreciative of any type of clarity on this.

Have you taken a look at the reference documentation and samples? Have you tried running the samples and making sample requests to test them out? Trying out a working application will help you easily understand most of these questions.
